# Using GPIO from bash: read only "1"

Tags: linux, bash, gpio

I'd like to set up an interrupt management on a NXP i.MX6 processor on `GPIO1_16`.

But before that, I wanted to verify that I can control this GPIO correctly.

So I can read and write on this GPIO with this following commands:

Read commands:

```
echo 16 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo in > /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/direction
cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/value
```

Write commands:

```
echo 16 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/direction
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/value
echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/value
```

My problem is that when I do read commands, I only get the value `1` (whether the cable connected to this GPIO is set to GND or VCC).
Also, my write commands don't seem to work because the LED connected to this GPIO never toggle.

This is very strange because these commands were working a few days ago.

Can you help me?

Comment: You shouldn't use sysfs for that. Try `gpiomon` utility. And if you had working setup, try to figure out what you have changed. Probably it's simply a disconnect somewhere on PCB level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the following table of the [i.XM6's datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/IMX6SDLIEC.pdf), `GPIO1_IO16` which corresponds to the power group of `NVCC_SD1` works between 1.65V and 3.6V.

[image]

This IO problem could come from a power supply error.